# JavaScript Table Sorting accented characters with sorttable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

I'm trying to make a sortable HTML table with Sorttable [Which's code is here](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js)

And it works just fine but I have some words with accented first characters (especially Á) in the `<td>`s and it just throws them after the Z.

I tried some ideas but I'm a beginner at Javascript and I couldn't make it work.

So please help me:
How can I make some changes in the code to sort the accented characters correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `sortLocaleCompare` property to `true`:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
    sortLocaleCompare : true
});
```

[**More Information**](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-locale-sort.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help? 
[jQuery Plugin: Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-locale-sort.html)

You may have to modify it slightly if the special character you are using is not supported but it should at least get you started.